# Should a question mark be used when describing a question but not asking the question?

Tags: punctuation, questions

For example:
Bob Smith, creates a film that questions what the best way to raise child is and what is happiness in the first place.

Should a question mark be used after each 'question'?

Comment: Is it a question or a statement?

Comment: What are the sentences?

Comment: It is a statement.

Comment: Should "what the best way to raise child is" have a question mark after it?

Comment: No, it is not a question. I asked "what is the best way?" – I asked what the best way is.

Comment: But a question can be used as a reference within a statement. "I asked him *How old are you?* and he wouldn't answer." The sentence ends with a period, since it's a statement, but it contains a question mark since the referenced question (with a question mark) is part of the overall statement. (Embedded quotation marks can also be used rather than italics.)

Comment: To get extra-pedantic, the sentence isn't consistent in the indirect question word-order. The second item should be *and what happiness is in the first place*.

Comment: A good test of whether a question mark should be used or not is to ask yourself whether the sentence would be pronounced with the intonation (mainly a rising tone in the last syllables) that implies that a question is being asked.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. The sentence is formed incorrectly. There is no inversion in the second part, no parallelism.  "Bob Smith, creates a film that questions what the best way to raise child **is** and what happiness **is** in the first place." HTH. See also [ell.se], especially if you are non-native speaker of the English language. Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

> Bob Smith, creates a film that questions what the best way to raise child is and what is happiness in the first place.

There is no question here, so no need for question marks. If making a statement which is not an interrogative, question marks are not appropriate.  And, no need for the comma.

The sentence may be rewritten:

> Bob Smith has created a film that asks: "What is the best way to raise a child?" and "What is happiness in the first place?".

Answer (score 0):

As the others have said, there is no question, so no question mark is needed. An important thing to note is that there should be no comma between "Smith" and "creates", for there should never be a comma separating a subject and a verb as such.